# Using @ManyToOne in where condition of JPQL JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I'm working on JPA and I got stuck with syntax or right approach to write JPQL, I have  entities: department and employee,

```
@Entity
Department

@OneToMany
Employee
-----------------------------------------

@Entity
Employee

@ManyToOne
Department
```

Now I have DOA where I am just adding condition dynamically to the JPQL query for where condition

I need to pull the employee who belong to XYZ department

So my JPQL looks like this

```
select * from employee where department='PK_OF_DEPT'
```

**NOTE : PK_OF_DEPT is the PK (some sequence)**

The error which I am getting is syntax error unknown column department, I tried giving department.id = still not working invalid path error,

**NOTE : Id is the attribute name in java object**

Can someone help me to get the right syntax, NOTE : I can't use FIND method since it need to be in that DOA which Is used dynamically for listing

Comment: Your JPQL does not have "SELECT *" because that would be invalid. All JPA docs on the internet explain how to do a JOIN in JPQL; why not read them?

Comment: Can you post your entity classes?

Answer (score 1):

There's not much information here, but try this

`from employee left join fetch employee.department where department.id='PK_OF_DEPT'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
@Query("select d.dname,d.deptno,e.ename,e.eno from Department d join d.employees e where d.id = ?1")
List<Object[]> getDepartmentAndEmployeeDetailsCustomQuery(int departId);
```